# How to get access to underlying GMSMapView from UIRepresentable MapView

Tags: swift, google-maps, swiftui

In my app I have a ViewModel(MapViewModel) class, a UIRepresentable class and ContentView. I am looking for a way to get access to GMSMapView view in the ViewModel that is created as a UIRepresentable class.

ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    @ObservedObject var mapViewModel : MapViewModel = MapViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            TabView(selection: self.$selection) {
                MapView()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "house")
                            Text("Home")
                        }
                }
                .tag(0)

                Text("Second Page")

                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                            Text("Settings")
                        }
                }
                .tag(1)

                Text("Third Page")

                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                            Text("Third Page")
                        }
                }
                .tag(2)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

MapViewModel.swift:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import GoogleMaps
import os

class MapViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    let lm = CLLocationManager()
    var myLocations =  [CLLocation]()


    override init() {

        super.init()

        lm.delegate = self
        lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        lm.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        lm.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        lm.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        lm.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

}

extension MapViewModel: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        //self.status = status

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        os_log("locationManager:didUpdateLocations: received location",log: Log.general, type: .debug)
    }
}
```

MapView.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMaps

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView {

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 30.267153, longitude: -97.7430608, zoom: 6.0)
        let gmsMapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        gmsMapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return gmsMapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Self.Context) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, GMSMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView

        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }       
    }
}

struct GoogleMapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

So any idea on how I can access the gmsMapView object in MapViewModel. I need access to draw lines on the map...Thanks!

Comment: In order to draw a line overlay (line between two CLLocations) on a map, you have to add either the MKPolyLine or GMSPolyline to the mapview. This means the code must have access to the googlemap mapview or mapkit mapview. One thought was to figure out a way to tell the UIViewRepresentable View to add the overlay, but not how sure to do this. Someone must have run into this besides me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this issue by defining the polyline overly value as @Published and accessing it via viewmodel in updateUI. So instead of trying to access the mapview from the viewmodel, I let the view add the polyline overlay. Hope this helps someone else. Thanks

ContentView.swift:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    @ObservedObject var mapViewModel: MapViewModel

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            TabView(selection: self.$selection) {
                MapView()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "house")
                            Text("Home")
                        }
                }
                .tag(0)

                Text("Second Page")

                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                            Text("Settings")
                        }
                }
                .tag(1)

                Text("Third Page")

                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                            Text("Third Page")
                        }
                }
                .tag(2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MapView:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObservedObject var mapViewModel = MapViewModel()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView {

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 30.5986015, longitude: -97.8210401, zoom: 20.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.animate(toViewingAngle: 45)
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Self.Context) {

        if (mapViewModel.polyline != nil) {
            print("updateUIView: Polyline = \(mapViewModel.polyline!.description)")
            os_log("updateUIView: Polyline = %{Public}s",log: Log.general, type: .debug, mapViewModel.polyline!.description)
            mapViewModel.polyline!.strokeColor = UIColor.red
            mapViewModel.polyline!.strokeWidth = 5.0
            mapViewModel.polyline!.map = mapView
        }

        if (mapViewModel.locChanged && mapViewModel.myLocations.count > 0) {

            print("updateUIView: Refocus camera on last location")
            os_log("updateUIView: Refocus camera on last location",log: Log.general, type: .debug, mapViewModel.polyline!.description)
            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (mapViewModel.myLocations.last?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (mapViewModel.myLocations.last?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 20.0)
            let _ = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, GMSMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView

        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

    }
}
```

MapViewModel:

```
class MapViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
             .
             .
             .    
    @Published var polyline: GMSPolyline?
    @Published var locChanged: Bool = false

    override init() {

        super.init()
             .
             .
             .       
        polyline = nil
    }

             .
             .
             .        
    func draw(myLocations: [CLLocation], color: UIColor) {

        os_log("MapViewController: Drawing Track for last two Locations",log: Log.general, type: .info)
        print("MapViewController: Drawing Track for last two Locations")
        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        let c1 = myLocations[myLocations.count - 1].coordinate
        let c2 = myLocations[myLocations.count - 2].coordinate
        path.add(c1)
        path.add(c2)
        polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        print("draw: Polyline = \(polyline!.description)")
        polyline!.strokeColor = color
        polyline!.strokeWidth = 5.0
    }

             .
             .
             .   

extension MapViewModel: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        os_log("locationManager:didUpdateLocations: received location",log: Log.general, type: .debug)

        guard let lastLocation: CLLocation = locations.last else {
            os_log("locationManager:didUpdateLocations: received null location",log: Log.general, type: .debug)
            return
        }


        if (myLocations.count >= 2) {

            os_log("MapViewController: updateLocation: Calling draw method with count = %{Public}s",log: Log.general, type: .debug, myLocations.count.description)

            self.draw(myLocations: self.myLocations, color:.red)
        }

             .
             .
             .    

        } else {

            os_log("LocationManager: Bad Location...",log: Log.general, type: .error)
            badLocationCount += 1
            locChanged = false
        }
    }
}
```